# How to Display previous comments on same page

Tags: php, html, mysql

Basically if the user want to comment on  the product,it needs to show the last comments on that product.

Here is the Comment.php code and here the data of comments inserting in to the database but the problem is i want to display the previous comments  of the product on the same page after the comment box.

Any suggestions?

```
       <?php


       include('GenericClasses/GenericCollectionClass.php');
       include('Models/UsersModel.php');
       include('DataObjects/Users.php');





  //If you are not submitting the form HTML will be directly shown

         if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) 
   {
   ?>


   <html>
      <head>
    <link href="facebox.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="CSS/screen.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
   </head>
   <body>



     <form action="" method="post" name="postsForm">
    <div class="UIComposer_Box">

    <span class="w">
    <textarea class="input" id="watermark" name="watermark" style="height:50px" cols="50" ></textarea>
     </span>       
    </div>
    <div align="left" style="height:30px; padding:10px 5px;">
            <input type="submit" name="submit"  style="background-color: orange;" value="postComment">


   </div>
  <?php          
   }
  else
  {
 //If you are submitting the form insert the details into database

     $Comments = $_POST['watermark'];

    if (!(empty($Comments))) 
    {
     $model = new UsersModel();

    $rowsCount = $model->InsertComments($Comments);
     }
    if ($rowsCount!=0)
     {

     echo'Inserted';

     } else{
        echo 'Not Inserted';
     }


     }
 ?>
    </form>

    </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Pass a product ID in URL, sanitize the value, fetch the records for that ID, loop them on the comment page

Comment: use select query and use max function to fetch the previous comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use any of the below query.

```
SELECT row 
FROM table 
WHERE id=(
    SELECT max(id) FROM table
    )
```

Note that if the value of max(id) is not unique, multiple rows are returned.
Or try this one

```
SELECT row from table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Can I retrieve the comments by using the time commented.. on that.

Comment: Share your table structure.If you have time in the table, you can use the second query